# Can I play the a video in the path of a file located in the hard disk out apatch server from a php file In the apatch?

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

I want to play a video in the path of a file located in the hard disk out apatch server from a php file in the apatch server, knowing that I am using xampp, I tried to write the code as follows.

```
<?php
$src="file://E:/Vtest/Fle.mp4";
?>
<video  src="<?php echo $src;?>" autoplay controls style="width:50%;height:50%;"></video>
```

But not working.
What to i do?

Comment: Would you like any website that you load in your browser being able to reference stuff on your local disk? Me neither, and that's what browsers typically and luckily prevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into a tutorial similar to this. I think you need to stream the video from you server, [PHP HTML5 Video Streaming Tutorial](https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial)

Also I think the src should point to the web location of the file for example:
$src="localhost/Fle.mp4" the path will depend on your exact location of the file.
Been a while since writing PHP but hope that helps